# XMPP over BOSH - jappix.com replies always with empty body

Tags: xmpp

I am implementing XMPP service in the browser using BOSH. I use [JAXL](http://code.google.com/p/jaxl/) library. I am able to manage the connection over BOSH to my localhost server (ejabberd). The session is started and the user is authenticated with no problem. However, when I just change the BOSH host to [jappix.com](https://jappix.com/bind), the very first response from the server is only empty body. Even if I repeat the request (according to [XEP-206](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html)) I still get only empty body so I'm unable to perform any other actions.

So that's my question: Is it possible to use jappix.com to handle my BOSH requests? Are there any limitations? How can I fix this issue? I'll provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am the Jappix.com owner!

Your question does not concern our service directly but more likely a node-xmpp-bosh - the BOSH server we are running - bug (?) that you can report on http://code.google.com/p/node-xmpp-bosh/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are absolutely right that issue belongs to node-xmpp-bosh server functionality. However, I have seen you have almost 200 living connections always I visit your site. How is it possible if there's a bug in the service?

Comment: Yes, we have up to 300 living connections on peak times, but everything is running fine.

We just have a small issue with node-xmpp-bosh which makes the server crash after a week (and before that the BOSH connection very very slow) due to CPU and RAM overuse. So we restart it every night at 4:30am to get everything clean. It disconnect the currently logged in users but there are very few of them using Jappix at night.

Comment: I don't know why, but when i try this BOSH server, it works flawlessly: http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind

Comment: @PavelS. Yes, that's a different BOSH server (software) - it's called Punjab and can be found here: http://code.stanziq.com/punjab

Comment: But the problem with Punjab is that is it pretty heavy for what it does. It works fine, but it makes the CPU and RAM get very high, and is a bit slow. node-xmpp-bosh is really really fast and lightweight, and supports more BOSH features. Also more reliable.